# После изменения размера формы форма зависает

Tags: c#

Подгоняю размер формы под отрисованный по координатам чертёж на PictureBox`е. Создал обработчик изменения размера и окончания изменения размера. В итоге всё отлично работает. Но если резко менять размер формы, то форма просто встанет в ступор. Приложение не зависает, в отладчике можно отследить все шаги. Всё работает как должно, но форма зависшая, при том что если попробовать её сдвинуть или изменить размер срабатывает F1_ResizeEnd. Просматривал по шагам, всё везде проходит, все методы завершают работу и обработчики тоже, но форма так и остаётся застывшей. Сколько не пытался, я не смог найти закономерность. Зависание после отпуская курсора. Во время самого изменения размера всё нормально, что бы я не делал. Есть способ выяснить с чём проблема?

```
private void F1_ResizeEnd(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (mass != null)
    {
        size_mark = false;
        f1.Height = -(int)ymin() + 60;
        f1.Width = (int)xmax() + 40;
        size_mark = true;
        p1.Refresh();
    }
}

private void F1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!size_mark)
        return;
    if (size_mark && mass != null)
    {
        if (f1.Width < 150 || f1.Height < 150)
            return;
        double size_x = xmax() - xmin();
        double size_y = ymax() - ymin();
        double x_koef = (f1.Width - 40) / (size_x + 20);
        double y_koef = (f1.Height - 40) / (size_y + 40);
        double koef = (x_koef < y_koef) ? x_koef : y_koef;
        g_mash_e(koef);
        g_move();
        p1.Width = f1.Width + 100;
        p1.Height = f1.Height + 100;
        p1.Refresh();
    }
}
```

Comment: Нужен минимальный самодостаточный, исполняемый фрагмент кода, в котором воспроизводится Ваша проблема.

Comment: Давид задержку перед срабатыванием кода в F1_ResizeEnd и проблема вроде прошла

Comment: Немного опечатался. Добавил*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавил задержку перед срабатыванием кода в F1_ResizeEnd и проблема прошла